Unix date utc 1 hour ago
Is there a way to get utc time 1 hour ago the same way that this works for local time?
date -d '1 hour ago' "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"
Something like date -u '1 hour ago' etc...?
Thanks
Different variations of date command with no luck

Just add -u and leavae the rest of the command-line the same. date -u -d '1 hour ago' +....
